# Why is my 12yr old cat howling (almost sounds like he's crying out for something or someone!)

Tags: cats, behavior, health, vocalizations

My 12 to 13-year-old male cat named Gordo has started to howl or I just don't know how to describe it, it is so heart-wrenching. I feel like crying when I hear him doing that I don't know what to do to help him.  He usually goes to the basement and does that so of course it echoes and makes it sound even louder. I'm wondering if it could be from one his age, I'm pretty sure he has some teeth that are bad cuz his breath isn't that great and two his brother Flacco that they were born together and lived together for 10 years passed away a year or so ago, so maybe he misses him. If anybody has any ideas could you pass them along to me, cuz I would really like to do something to help him, cuz it's really making my heart bleed hearing him cry out like that.  And it's not just at night, it's at any time too, and if he's suffering or needs something that bad I want to be able to give it to him. And any answer is fine there's no wrong answer thank you.

Answer (score 4):

Sorry if this may sound harsh, but the answer is so simple:

**Get him checked by a vet.**

The most common problems that can cause a lot of pain to check are:

- Urinary stones and kidney health in general
- Any inflammation, but especially of the liver or pancreas
- Bad teeth
- Arthritis

If your vet has more ideas, listen to them. They are the experts, I am not.

Also try to analyze when he starts howling. Is it after a certain activity like eating or peeing? That points towards a medical problem like pancreatitis or kidney stones.

Is it mostly at night? Then he might be bored and calling out for a cat lady to have fun with. Does he always face a certain direction or object when howling? Then he might be hearing something (like a mouse or a cat lady) in that direction and call out to them.

One last word about missing his brother. If he passed away a year ago, then Gordo has probably forgotten about him. Cats have different brains than humans and think differently. Projecting human emotions on animals often leads to misunderstanding their intentions. Cats don't have the same concept of "family" as we humans have. To him it never mattered whether this other cat was from the same litter or not. And now he's long got used to living without his brother. So whatever this howling is about, it's certainly not about missing his brother.

Answer (score 4):

When a senior cat starts to vocalise more, there's always a reason for the change, though reading a cat's mind to understand why is difficult.

It could be pain, though in my experience cats tend to be more subdued than vocal when they have chronic pain.

He could want more or different food, or feel thirsty and want water.

He could just want more attention.

It could be a cognitive problem — cats do get forms of dementia, although it's not well understood. There are treatments that can help with this.

Or it could be a medical problem. With a vocal cat, first thing I would rule out is hyperthyroidism (overactive thyroid). These cats tend to be very vocal or restless, and also are commonly losing weight, usually have a strong or increased appetite, and may be vomiting more. Physical exam findings are usually fairly obvious, the condition is confirmed with a blood test, and is very treatable. Other medical causes are possible, but this is one of the first to rule out.

If there is no medical cause, then there may be medications that can be prescribed to keep him more calm.

Please give us an update once you have had Gordo examined by his vet.